# How to use GPG exported keys in libgcrypt?

Tags: c, cryptography, gnupg

Was wondering how could I use private/public keys exported by GPG to be used by libgcrypt? Libgcrypt needs to s-expression structures with its associated mpi values and I don't know how to extract that from the GPG export :(

Thanks in advance!